# Facebook marketing API Error #100: Tried accessing nonexisting field (approximate_count) on node type (Saved_Audience)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

Until mid-November my application getting via the Facebook Marketing API the approximate reach of saved target audiences was working perfectly. Now it's getting the following error message: "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (approximate_count) on node type (SavedAudience)".

Did the name of the field "approximate_count" change or what could be the problem? Any hints much appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is changed to approximate_count_64bit.
See [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/04/06/moving-from-32-64-bit-limit-potential-reach/) please.